# What are the drawbacks to using a private local repository for Hudson jobs?

Tags: maven, hudson

Hudson provides the option to have a Maven build job utilize a private local repository, or use the common one from the Maven installation, i.e. one shared with other build jobs.  I have the sense that our builds should use private local repositories to ensure that they are clean builds.  However, this causes performance issues, particularly with respect to bandwith of downloading all dependencies for each job -- we also have the jobs configured to start with a clean "workspace", whcih seems to nuke the private maven repo along with the rest of the build space.

For daily, continuous integration builds, what are the pros and cons of choosing whether or not to use a private local maven repository for each build job?  Is it a big deal to share a local repo with other jobs?

Comment: Define "private local repository." Do you mean like Nexus? Also, can you describe the performance problems you are seeing and how you know using a local repository is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting the jenkins documentation, you would use `private Maven repository` if

> - You end up having builds incorrectly succeed, just because your have all the dependencies in your local repository, despite that fact that
>     none of the repositories in POM might have them.
> - You have problems regarding having concurrent Maven processes trying to use the same local repository.

Furthermore

> When using this option, consider setting up a Maven artifact manager
>   so that you don't have to hit remote Maven repositories too often.

Also you could explore your [scm's clean option](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Clean-Workspace-Before-Each-Build-td3460928.html) (rather than workspace clean) to avoid this repository getting nuked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I kind of already knew the two points about false build success and repo contention.  However, I'm wondering if anyone can give conrete specifics about what contexts would cause this?  For instance, repo contention between concurrent maven processes?  Is this going to happen all the time?  In a CI environment, we have builds running continously?

Comment: Thanks for the last advice. It's also a good idea to put SVN (or whatever) checkout to some subdirectory of the workspace. Otherwise Jenkins will still wipe out the Maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sonatype recommends using a local Nexus instance, even though their own research shows (State of the Software Supply Chain report 2015) that less then 5% of traffic to Maven Central comes from such repositories.

To get back to the question, assuming you have a local Nexus instance and high bandwidth connectivity (tens of Gbps at least) between your build server (e.g. Jenkins) and Nexus, then I can see few drawbacks to using a private local repo, in fact I would call the decrease in build performance a reasonable trade-off.

The above said, what exactly are we trading off? We are accepting a small performance penalty on the downside and on the upside we know with 100% certainty that independent, clean builds against with our local Nexus instance as proxy works.

The latter is important because consider the scenario where the local repo on the build server (probably in the jenkins' user home directory) has an artefact that is not cached in Nexus (this is not improbable if you started off your builds against Maven Central). This out-of-sync scenario is suboptimal because it is possible to get a scenario where your cache TTL settings in Nexus means that builds fail if Nexus' upstream connectivity to Central was down temporarily.

Finally, to add more to the benefits side of the trade-off, I spent hours today getting an artefact in the shared Jenkins user .m2/repository today. Earlier on in the day upstream connectivity to Central was locally up and down for hours (mysterious issue in enterprise context). In the end I deleted the entire shared jenkins user .m2/repository so it all be retrieved from the local Nexus.

It's worth considering having builds using a local .m2/repository (in jenkins user home directory) as well as builds using private local repositories (fast and less fast builds). In my case however I may opt for private local repositories only in the first instance - I may be able to accept the penalty if I optimise the build by focussing on low hanging fruit (e.g. split up multi module build).